# Shell Parameter expansion not working in AIX

Tags: ksh, aix, variable-substitution

I'm trying to substitute a specific string that isn't working in AIX but when I run it on RHEL I'm able to get the expected output.

Here's the command:

```
filename=25_032021_abcdefghijklmn.txt; mv /u/foo/test/25_032021_test_${filename:10:14}.txt /u/foo/test/25_032021_test_${filename:10:14}.txt.tmpExtension
```

Here's the error I get when running this command on AIX

`ksh: /u/foo/test/25_032021_test_${filename:10:14}.txt: 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.`

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${param:offset:length}` was introduced by `ksh93`¹, it was not available in `ksh88`. So you need to make sure the script is interpreted by ksh93, not ksh88.

Also remember parameter expansions must be quoted in most Bourne-like shells at least when in list contexts.

You can type <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> in an interactive `ksh` with line editor enabled (after `set -o emacs` or `vi` or `gmacs`) to check its version.

Here, instead of `${filename:10:14}`, you could use

```
filename=25_032021_abcdefghijklmn.txt
id="${filename%.*}" # remove extension from the end
id="${id#*_*_}"     # remove up to second _ from the start
mv "/u/foo/test/25_032021_test_$id.txt" \
   "/u/foo/test/25_032021_test_$id.txt.tmpExtension"
```

To remove 10 characters from the start instead of `*_*_`, use `${param#??????????}`. So, the equivalent of `id=${filename:10:14}` assuming `filename` has at least 24 characters would be:

```
id=${filename#??????????}       # remove 10 characters from the start
id=${id%"${id#??????????????}"} # remove from the end: $id stripped of
                                # its first 14 characters
```

Those `${param#pattern}` and `${param%pattern}` were introduced in earlier versions of `ksh` (already there in ksh85) and even specified by POSIX for `sh`, so you should find them in any `sh` or `ksh` these days.

Or you could go the ancient way from the pre-ksh days and resort to `expr`².

```
id=`expr "x$filename" : 'x.\{10\}\(.\{14\}\)'`
```

Or:

```
id=`expr "x$filename" : 'x.\{10\}\(.\{0,14\}\)'`
```

(for a stricter equivalent to ksh93's `${filename:10:14}` when `$filename` has fewer than 24 characters).

Beware `expr` will return with a failure exit status if what it outputs is a representation of the number 0 or the empty string or the regexp doesn't match, so you may need to append a `|| true` if you have enabled the `errexit` option, so it doesn't cause the shell to exit on files called `123456789_00000000000000.txt` for instance.

That `expr` approach also won't work properly if the *id* ends in newline characters (which would be stripped by the command substitution).

---

<sup>¹ also available in `bash` since 2.0 (late 1996), `mksh` since R30 (2007) and `zsh` since 4.3.11 (late 2010), though `zsh` had `$param[first,last]` since 2.0 in 1991.</sup>

<sup>² though the `\{n,m\}` regexp operator is standard today, it wouldn't have been available in those pre-ksh days, and you'd have had to replace `.\{10\}` with `..........` for instance.</sup>